# Ignore automated unit tests when (only) README.md is changed

Tags: unit-testing, github, github-actions

I am using python unittests as a GitHub action/workflow but my question applies also to 3rd party solutions such as Travis.

Whenever I commit/push, the unittests get automatically triggered, as expected. However, some times I just want to change only the `README.md` without triggering the unittests on push. Is this somehow possible?

This is an essential feature, especially now that Travis has limited free tokens which would be wasted when re-running the tests just for a README commit.

If a solution doesn't / shouldn't exist, is there any reasoning against it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to skip running tests when you have only changes which aren't relevant to the tests is to put your test commands in some sort of Makefile or shell script, say, `script/cibuild`.

Then, in that script, do something like this:

```
if git diff --raw "$GITHUB_BASE_REF...$GITHUB_SHA" | cut -f2 | grep -vqsF README.md
then
    echo "Skipping tests due to README-only changes"
    exit 0
fi
```

You will, of course, need to adjust this for Travis, which doesn't use variable starting with `GITHUB`.

Doing something like the above lets you have the greatest degree of flexibility for customization, but if you only want to exclude paths and you're working with pull requests and pushes, you can also [configure that using a path pattern](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths):

```
on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
    - README.md
```

The way this is done will vary depending on the CI provider; Travis may or may not have such a feature.